# How to use $index inside double curly braces to bind multiple variables data in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can we use $index like this below in angular js.
{{appName($index)Data}}

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below

"{{YouranyvariableName}}_{{$index}}"

To Concatinate Values use

{{$index}} |#| {{youranyvariablename}}

Note : |#| i have used here to concatinate the values.